# expected distance btw random point inside the circle and its centre

Tags: probability, statistics

Let us randomly choose a point inside the circle of radius $1$. Find the expected distance between the point and the centre of the circle.

I approached it in a such way:  no matter where we choose a point, we can draw a radius from the centre such that this point will be on it. Thus, this problem is about finding the expected point randomly on the interval $(0,1)$, which is $0.5$, obviously.

But I really can't figure out how to show that the expected point on this interval is $0.5$.

Comment: Hint to get you on the right track: consider the probability that the point is within $0.5$ of the centre. Also, did you know that that emoji isn't supposed to symbolise frustration, but success? Think of it like a "booyeah!" (see [it's unicode description](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F624))

Comment: That depends on how one interprets "randomly": is it radially random or just uniformly random over the whole disk?

Comment: Thank you all, guys! I got the idea! Arthur, that is really unexpected information, thx

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you mean randomly within the circle.

So cut the circle into thin rings with radius $r$ and width $dr$. Then the area is $2\pi r dr$. The probability of getting a point inside this ring is $$\frac{2\pi r dr}{\pi \times 1^2}$$

So the expected value of $r$ should be

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2\pi r dr}{\pi}r=\int_0^12r^2dr=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Thank u very much, but can you explain this expression please? Following the hints of other people I went to the conclusion that the expected distance is = sqrt(0.5) to get 0.5 probability to be at the "center half" of the circle.

Comment: This is much more clear! Very elegant, thanx

Comment: @Alice Because $\langle r \rangle = \sum rP(r)$.

Comment: @Alice The answer should be greater than $1/2$ because $0 \le r \le 1$, but the larger the $r$, the higher the probability.

Comment: Thank you for your time again, ur the best

Answer (score 1):

As explained in my comment, this really depends on your interpretation.

In my opinion most people would take "randomly" as "uniformly random" with regard to the area elements. In this sense, the probability density to land on any particular point in the disc is $\frac1\pi$, so the expected radius will be
$$\int_{x^2+y^2\le 1} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\, \frac1\pi dxdy.$$
I am gonna leave the computational details to you. (Hint: use polar coordinates for change of variables.)

If, alternatively, the "randomly" means radially random, then the expectation is $1/2$ just as you said.