# Bounds of integration for this expected value question.

Tags: expected-value

Kelly throws a dart at a circular dartboard of
radius $3$ feet. Let X and Y denote the location where the dart lands. Assume
that $−3 ≤ X ≤ 3$ and $−3 ≤ Y ≤ 3$ and $X^2 + Y^2 ≤ 9$, i.e., the dart lands on
the dartboard. Moreover, assume that the dart’s location is Uniform on the
dartboard, i.e.,
$f (x, y) = 1/(9π)$ if $x, y$ are on the dartboard, i.e., $x^2 + y^2 ≤ 9$

Let $D = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$ be the distance from the dart to the center of the
dartboard. Find $E(D)$.

I need help finding the bounds of integration to find $E(D)$ can someone lend me a hand?

Comment: What do you think they are?

Comment: I was thinking it would be $r = 0$ to $3$ and $\theta = 0$ to $2\pi$ with an double polar integral, but the issue is that I'm given $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ and that's not polar...

Comment: If you want to use polar coordinates, you could express $D$ in polar coordinates too. Don’t forget the Jacobian for change of variables.

Comment: so please tell me if I got this right $E(D)$ would be would be $\int_0^3 \int_0^{2\pi} r^2\cfrac{1}{9\pi}drd\theta$?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: I just realized I switched up the integrals by accident in the above. But I get 2 as my final answer which double checking with a calculator seems right. You said earlier "If you want to use polar coordinates", is there an alternative and easier way to do this question?

Comment: I think polar is easier, but otherwise I would say $X \in [-3,3]$ and $Y \in [-\sqrt{9-X^2},\sqrt{9-X^2}]$. Also, this is a related post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438705/expected-distance-btw-random-point-inside-the-circle-and-its-centre

Comment: Sorry ignore that last comment. I'm just trying to find out what I unlocked on stack exchange

Comment: Welcome to SE. If you write up your answer and explain it well, I’ll upvote it.